# Access modifiers inheritance: on abstract methods

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, abstract

On one hand, I have an abstract class with an abstract method.
On the other hand, I have a child class which overrides the abstract method and specifies the "public" access modifier to it.

Is it meaningful at all what visibility I give to my original abstract class' abstract method?

Comment: Well, yes it is; while you can broaden the visibility of an implemented method, you cannot restrict it. Note that methods in interfaces are `public abstract` by default as well, so all implementations of interfaces have to have the `public` modifier (even though there are no restrictions on the visibility of the interface itself)

Comment: Well, if my children's are going to be public, then I don't know what best practice should I apply for the accessor of my parent

Comment: I guess the thing I should question to me is whether do I want to restrict the possibility of using the method exclusively within a package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, subclasses are allowed to "increase" the visibility of a method when overriding it, but not "decrease" it.  I.e. a `protected` method can be overridden and made `public`, but a `public` method can't be overridden and made `protected`.

The meaning of keeping a superclass method `protected` (not necessary to have the superclass or the method `abstract` here) is that it allows subclasses to override the method and either keep it `protected` or make it `public`.  If the superclass makes the method `public`, then that forces any subclass that overrides that method to have that method remain `public`.

The [JLS, Section 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3), covers these requirements:

> The access modifier (§6.6) of an overriding or hiding method must provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as follows:
>
> - If the overridden or hidden method is public, then the overriding or hiding method must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method is protected, then the overriding or hiding method must be protected or public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method has package access, then the overriding or hiding method must not be private; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Well... there is one exception. If I make the method private :). I really would like to have a mechanism to force "private method on my children"

Comment: But `private` methods cannot be overridden.  It would be pointless to override a `private` method, because it's only accessible in the class in which it's defined anyway.

Comment: That's why I say it, as private refers to the very same method in contrast to the other cases (where the modifier itself is forwarded as a lower limit) there is no way to have an inherited method private-scoped

Comment: No, an inherited method cannot be made `private`.